# Nested link in label for Wicket

Tags: java, wicket

I'm wondering if something like this is possible in wicket:

```
<span wicket:id="label"><a wicket:id="link"></a></span>
```

Where the link can be rendered on the desired place of the label (without the need of splitting it).

For example, consider the following label: "The [LINK]roses[/LINK] are red"
If 'The' and 'are red' are dynamic, we have to use multiple labels:

```
<span wicket:id="firstPartLabel"/><a wicket:id="link"/><span wicket:id="lastPartLabel">
```

Which is pretty ugly, we cannot insert the link dinamicaly so that, considering the label
`The ${link} are red` 
and replace the placeholder with a proper Link?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried creating a new Wicket element which extends Label and contains a link? That's how I would try. Then in the HTML you'd have a link and in the Java file for that LinkLabel you could create your link.

Comment: Actually I've not, I supposed someone already made this, but I will give it a try, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this creating a custom Panel called LinkLabel. The component still uses "hard-coded markup" for both the labels, but at least its working.

You can use it this way:

```
LinkLabel myLabel = new LinkLabel("description",
        "First ${link} second", "my link", new ILinkListener() {

            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

            @Override
            public void onLinkClicked() {
                // Your desired onClick action
            }
        });
```

The java code for the component is the following:

```
public class LinkLabel extends Panel {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public LinkLabel(String id, String model, String linkName,
            ILinkListener linkListener) {
        super(id);
        setRenderBodyOnly(true);
        String[] split = model.split("\\$\\{link\\}");
        if (split.length == 2) {
            Label first = new Label("first", split[0]);
            Label second = new Label("second", split[1]);

            add(first);
            add(second);
            add(generateLink(linkListener, linkName));
        } else if (split.length == 1) {
            Label first = new Label("first", split[0]);
            Label second = new Label("second");
            second.setVisible(false);
            add(first);
            add(second);
            add(generateLink(linkListener, linkName));
        } else {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException(
                    "LinkLabel needs the ${link} placeholder!");
        }
    }

    private Link<?> generateLink(final ILinkListener linkListener,
            String linkName) {
        Label linkLabel = new Label("linkLabel", linkName);
        Link<String> link = new Link<String>("link") {
            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

            @Override
            public void onClick() {
                linkListener.onLinkClicked();
            }
        };
        link.add(linkLabel);
        return link;
    }
}
```

Markup for the component:

```
<wicket:panel>
    <span wicket:id="first"></span>
    <a wicket:id="link"><span wicket:id="linkLabel"></span></a>
    <span wicket:id="second"></span>
</wicket:panel>
```

Answer (score 3):

Wicket messages support what you're looking for:

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/WICKET/Everything+about+Wicket+internationalization#EverythingaboutWicketinternationalization-Puttingwicketcomponentsintothemessage

Answer (score 0):

If what you want to do is something like Twitter's hashtag/username links (to process plain text and add links to special segments), you can extend Label to do that. Just search the text for the special words (here I used a regex Pattern, but you could use any other method) and replace them with the HTML for the link.

In this example, `isInternalRef` creates a link to an Ajax behavior. It could be also used to create links to resources, pages, and other types of components (some handle direct links, some don't).

This class is a very simple example, it's not intended to support all of Twitter's syntax.

```
public class TweetLabel extends Label {

    private static final Pattern USERNAME_HASHTAG_PATTERN = Pattern.compile("\\B([@#*])([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);

    private transient CharSequence body;

    public TweetLabel(String id) {
        super(id);
    }
    public TweetLabel(String id, String label) {
        super(id, label);
    }
    public TweetLabel(String id, Serializable label) {
        super(id, label);
    }
    public TweetLabel(String id, IModel<?> model) {
        super(id, model);
    }

    protected void onLinkClicked(AjaxRequestTarget target, String word) {
        target.appendJavaScript("alert('You clicked on \"" + JavaScriptUtils.escapeQuotes(word) + "\", and the server knows...');");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onConfigure() {
        super.onConfigure();

        // process text here, because we can add behaviors here, but not at onComponentTagBody()
        body = processText(getDefaultModelObjectAsString());
    }

    @Override
    public void onComponentTagBody(MarkupStream markupStream, ComponentTag openTag) {
        replaceComponentTagBody(markupStream, openTag, body);
    }

    /** 
     * based on Matcher.replaceAll()
     */
    private CharSequence processText(String text) {
        Matcher m = USERNAME_HASHTAG_PATTERN.matcher(text);
        boolean result = m.find();
        if (result) {
            StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
            do {
                final String replacement = getLinkedTextAndAddBehavior(text, m.start(), m.end());
                m.appendReplacement(sb, replacement);
                result = m.find();
            } while (result);
            m.appendTail(sb);
            return sb;
        }
        return text;
    }

    private String getLinkedTextAndAddBehavior(String fullText, int start, int end) {

        final String matchedString = fullText.substring(start, end);
        final int length = matchedString.length();
        final String prefix = matchedString.substring(0, 1);
        final String identifier = matchedString.substring(1, length);
        final boolean isUsername = prefix.equals("@");
        final boolean isHashtag = prefix.equals("#") && (start == 0 || fullText.charAt(start - 1) != '&');
        final boolean isInternalRef = prefix.equals("*");

        final String replacement;
        if (isUsername) {

            final String url = "https://twitter.com/" + identifier;
            replacement = "<a href='" + url + "'>" + matchedString + "</a>";

        } else if (isHashtag) {

            final String url = "https://twitter.com/search?src=hash&q=" + UrlEncoder.QUERY_INSTANCE.encode(matchedString, "UTF-8");
            replacement = "<a href='" + url + "'>" + matchedString + "</a>";

        } else if (isInternalRef) {

            final LinkedWordBehavior behavior = getOrAddBehavior(new LinkedWordBehavior(identifier));
            final String rawFunction = behavior.getCallbackScript().toString();
            replacement = String.format("<a href='#' onclick='%s;return false;'>%s</a>", rawFunction, matchedString);

        } else {
            replacement = matchedString;
        }

        return replacement;
    }

    /**
     * Verify if the behavior was already added, add if not.
     */
    private LinkedWordBehavior getOrAddBehavior(LinkedWordBehavior behavior) {
        final List<LinkedWordBehavior> behaviors = getBehaviors(LinkedWordBehavior.class);
        final int index = behaviors.indexOf(behavior);
        if (index > -1) {
            return behaviors.get(index);
        } else {
            add(behavior);
            return behavior;
        }
    }

    private final class LinkedWordBehavior extends AbstractDefaultAjaxBehavior {
        private final String word;
        public LinkedWordBehavior(String word) {
            this.word = word;
        }
        @Override
        protected void respond(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
            final String word = TweetLabel.this.getRequest().getRequestParameters().getParameterValue("word").toString();
            if (!Strings.isEmpty(word)) {
                TweetLabel.this.onLinkClicked(target, word);
            }
        }
        protected void updateAjaxAttributes(AjaxRequestAttributes attributes) {
            super.updateAjaxAttributes(attributes);
            attributes.getExtraParameters().put("word", word);
        }
        @Override
        public int hashCode() {
            return word.hashCode();
        }
        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object obj) {
            return word.equals(((LinkedWordBehavior) obj).word);
        }
    }
}
```

**UPDATED** changed the example to handle ajax requests with Behaviors. There are other ways to do it. For example, you could have a single behavior to handle all links, or use a resource, but this way looked cleaner to me.

Comment: Thanks, I need also a callback on the linki action, how can I add it to your solution? (i.e. onClick()).

Answer (score 0):

One **easy** way is to build up the link as a `String` yourself using standard `<a href=""> </a>` tags.  Your Java code can then supply this `String` as a `Label` with the attribute `.setEscapeModelStrings(false)`.  Your html markup is a standard Wicket label.

In the markup, I suggest underlining the Lorem ipsum text (which will not be seen after Wicket replaces the label).  This can help to remind you that this label is going to be a link, when you are designing your markup.

*Example markup:*

```
<span wicket:id="mylabel"><u>Lorem ipsum dolor</u></span>
```

*Example Java:*

```
    this.createLink("mylabel", "The", "ROSES", "are red", "https://testurl.com");
}

private Void createLink(String label, String textBefore, String textLink, String textAfter, String url)
{
    String htmlLink = "<a href='" + url + "'>" + textLink + "</a>";
    String labelText = textBefore + htmlLink + textAfter;
    this.add(new Label(label, labelText).setEscapeModelStrings(false));
}
```